# Passing HTML as data via jQuery ajax() & in URLs change to `&amp;`

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am grabbing the HTML of a page and trying to send it as a string to a PHP web service via jQuery's ajax() function. When I get the paramter on the PHP side the &s in the URLs within the HTML (e.g. src attribute of images) are converted to `&amp;` and the links aren't working.

Example:

```
<img src="https://somesite.com/path/file.php?foo=bar&biz=buz&bat=bot">
```

Result:

```
<img src="https://somesite.com/path/file.php?foo=bar&amp;biz=buz&amp;bat=bot">
```

Comment: Could we see your code, please?

Comment: The encoded `&amp;` is correct, as ampersands should be encoded in HTML attributes. It is likely encoded that way in the browser before you grab the element, even if your raw HTML doesn't deliver it that way. The browser is "fixing" it for you.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I got unencoded `&` in PHP.

Comment: To decode it server-side in PHP, you might wish to look at [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Comment: It's not encoded that way before I grab it. I've confirmed it. It is encoded though, with spaces represented as %20. The URL with the ;&amp does not work unless you manually replace the encoding with &. I don't want to have to regex the HTML on the PHP side to find all the images and replace the &amp; characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to use [htmlspecialchars_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) on the PHP side to convert the `&amp;` back to `&`.

Answer (score -1):

encode your html on client side:

```
var html = '<img src="https://somesite.com/path/file.php?foo=bar&biz=buz&bat=bot">';
var encodedHtml = btoa(html);
```

Post it to server and decode response string to html with php:

```
$html = base64_decode( $encoded_html );
```

Comment: I tried that but got this in console:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`